# How to use the Windows scripting host "//E" command line argument?

Tags: command-line-arguments, wsh

I am trying to use the windows scripting host command line argumet to run a .js file. However, everytime I run I get this error that it cannot find the script engine irrespective of providing absolute path or "wscript.exe" or just the name "wscript". I must use the "//E" option to to specify the script engine to use, to test something.

I tried ***"scriptfile.js //E:C:\Windows\System32\wscript"***, ***"scriptfile.js //E:C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe"*** and ***"scriptfile.js //E:wscript"*** but nothing helps. It gives me the error *"Can't find script engine C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe" for script scriptfile.js"*

Msdn links do not provide a sample command usage so it almost of no use to me, except that they inform me to check the spelling and the script engine - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s39f60wz(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s39f60wz%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kbz7235(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kbz7235%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

So if someone has successfully used the //E option to specify that "wscript" script engine needs to be used specifically, please do let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the options for the //E: are either **//E:jscript** or **//E:vbscript**

Try:

```
wscript //E:jscript scriptfile.js
```

here's my attempt:
[image]

you can type wscript /? on the command line to see the options.

[image].

Answer (score 1):

The `//E` argument is used to specify the script language rather than the path to the script host executable. But if you use standard file extensions — .js for JScript and .vbs for VBScript — Windows Script Host will automatically detect the script language, and there's no need to use the //E argument.

Somewhat detailed explanation of the //E parameter is given in this TechNet article:
[Running Scripts from the Command Line](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156587.aspx).

Having said that, to run a .js file you can simply use the following command:

```
wscript C:\myscript.js
```

This will run the script using the GUI version of the script host (so that the `WScript.Echo` output is displayed in message boxes).
To run a script using the console version of the script host (so that the `WScript.Echo` output is send to the console), use the following command:

```
cscript C:\myscript.js
```

To run a script using the default version of the script host, simply type the script name at the command prompt:

```
C:\myscript.js
```

Comment: Thanks, now it's all clear. I know how to run scripts and use wscript and cscript; however one program I installed took over as the default engine for my script files. So to force my script to use jscript, I use the above //E argument.